# Strange Clipping in DC.js Stacked Area Chart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm using DC.js to create a stacked area chart of percentages. However when I go to render it I get some weird artifacts as seen here:

[image: Area Chart with black clipping artifacts]

This looks like some sort of clipping artifact but I'm unsure of where it's coming from. Here's the code I'm using to render this chart:

```
 dc.lineChart("#stacked-area-volume-chart")
    .renderArea(true)
    .width(colmd12Width)
    .height(200)
    .transitionDuration(0)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40})
    .dimension(date)
    .group(lastActionsByDay, "Invalid Phone Out Of Business")
    .valueAccessor(function(d) { return d.value.InvalidPhoneOutOfBusiness.sum / d.value.count; })
    .stack(lastActionsByDay, "POC-NI Competitor", function(d){
      return d.value.POCNICompetitor.sum / d.value.count;
    })
    .stack(lastActionsByDay, "POC-NI No Need", function(d){
      return d.value.POCNINoNeed.sum / d.value.count;
    })
    .stack(lastActionsByDay, "(blank)", function(d){
      return d.value.blank.sum / d.value.count;
    })
    .stack(lastActionsByDay, "Not Decision Maker", function(d){
      return d.value.NotDecisionMaker.sum / d.value.count;
    })
    .stack(lastActionsByDay, "POC-Follow Up", function(d){
      return d.value.POCFollowUp.sum / d.value.count;
    })
    .stack(lastActionsByDay, "Not Interested Competitor", function(d){
      return d.value.NotInterestedCompetitor.sum / d.value.count;
    })
    .stack(lastActionsByDay, "Requested Information", function(d){
      return d.value.RequestedInformation.sum / d.value.count;
    })
    .stack(lastActionsByDay, "Not Interested No Need", function(d){
      return d.value.NotInterestedNoNeed.sum / d.value.count;
    })
    .stack(lastActionsByDay, "Call No Answer", function(d){
      return d.value.CallNoAnswer.sum / d.value.count;
    })
    .stack(lastActionsByDay, "Left Voice Message", function(d){
      return d.value.LeftVoiceMessage.sum / d.value.count;
    })
    .elasticY(true)
    .transitionDuration(200)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; })))
    .xUnits(d3.time.days);
```

Comment: Do you have dc.css loaded on your page? This looks a bit like what can happen if the lines in the area chart are not set to `fill: none`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon I think that got it.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks for confirming.